# How to unlock row in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, locking

I've probably killed (`-9`) somehow process which locked a row in my table.
Now whenever I try to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE id=6 FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
```

I get:

> ERROR:  could not obtain lock on row in relation "my_table"`.

How can I **unlock** that row?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out somehow.

- I made `select * from pg_locks;`,
- checked `pid` similar to that which i killed.
- Then I made `ps aux | grep suspicious_pid`,
- i got something like: `postgres: q-back my_project ::1(63686) idle in transaction`.
- then `kill suspicious_pid`, where `suspicious_pid` is number of PID of course.

Comment: It's better to use `pg_cancel_backend(pid)` or `pg_terminate_backend(pid)`. But the real question is: why do you have connections that start transactions but never commit?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for tip. I had an async worker which locked the row at the start of working and kept it locked until finish download from server and finally commit. I've killed it while it was working and the transaction survived opened. I have no better idea how to explain that..